# Displaying stream with OpenCV sometimes receives an empty frame and freezes

Tags: c++, opencv, rtsp

I try to read and show a video stream with OpenCV (C++) from an IP-Camera. Sometimes the applicatons freezes for several seconds and than reports that an empty frame was received. I am searching for a possibility to drop empty frames and just read the next frame in a way that the video does not freeze for several seconds.

I used the simple example code below and tried to reread the next frame when a empty frame appears. The video starts runing normal, but after some time it freezes for several seconds. 
I opened the stream in the VLC media player and there it runs fluent. 
I tried different ways to read the next frame: for example cap.read(frame); instead of cap >> frame; I also tried to change the delay in the waitKey but allways with the same result. I do not want to use tcp (insert ?tcp at the end of the stream address), because in the final application I can not tolerate large delays.

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){

  string filename = "rtsp://[myStreamIP]:554/stream.mjpeg"
  VideoCapture cap(filename); 

  if(!cap.isOpened()){
    return 1;
  }

  int frameNumber = 0;  
  while(cap.isOpened()){

    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    frameNumber++;

    while (frame.empty()){
          cout << "empty frame" << "-";
      cap >> frame;

    }

    cout << frameNumber << "-";
    imshow( "Frame", frame );
    waitKey(1);

  }

  cap.release();
  destroyAllWindows();  
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get looks something like this:

1-2-...-123-[several seconds pass and nothing happens and the video freezes]-empty frame-124-125-
...

I would understand a certain delay (still much smaller) when I have to try to reread a frame for several times, but I do not understand why the delay appers before the first time "empty frame" in the output.

Comment: could you try to measure how long the read() method (>>) and how long the empty() method takes, when there is an empty frame?

Comment: read took 30000ms and empty 200ms

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is good practice to look in a loop for empty frames, I would rather use an if else statement, but I don't think this is the problem:

```
Mat frame;
while(cap.isOpened()){

    cap >> frame;
    frameNumber++;

    if(frame.empty()){
      cout << "empty frame" << "-";
      continue;
    }

    cout << frameNumber << "-";
    imshow( "Frame", frame );
    waitKey(1);
}
```

And declare your `Mat frame` outside the while loop, so you can reuse the same memory space.

Edit:
When reading the [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) you can see that the read-call is a combined call to grab() and retrieve(). Where retrieve() is the "slow" function, which writes in your picture in cv::Mat and grab() just grabs the next picture and returns a bool, if there is a picture or not. Maybe something like this works:

```
Mat frame;
while(cap.isOpened()){

    if(!cap.grab()){
      cout << "empty frame" << "-";
      continue;
    }

    frame = cap.retrieve();
    frameNumber++;

    cout << frameNumber << "-";
    imshow( "Frame", frame );
    waitKey(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I applied the changes you suggested, but as expected, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: I am doing something similar and facing the same issue. And as you mentioned earlier, this does not seem to solve the problem.